# How I can remove a body elasticity? (andengine)

Tags: andengine, elasticity

My character's body keeps bouncing.

```
body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 1, 1));
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, body, true, true));
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace with: `PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0, 0)`, so that elasticity is 0.